# Code for automatically checking when there's an appointment available

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Python programming but with the help of some friends and ChatGPT I was able to write a basis for my intended purpose. As the title suggests, I want to automatically check every 10 min or so whenever there's an appointment to get my Italian citizenship. There is a sign in website and once you sign in, you have to press a button to check for availability. If there are no dates, a message pops up saying there aren't any available dates and you must press an OK button to back out. My code works up to the point of signing in. Once I sign in, I get an "Unavailable" message at the top left corner of a blank site. Maybe it is due to security reasons or something but I would like to share my code with you so maybe you guys can let me know what the problem is. Again, there may be some conceptual errors, since it is my first time ever experiencing Python. Any questions you may have ill be glad to answer them!

Thank you very much! I will proceed to paste the code below.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def check_appointments():
    # set up the email account
    sender_email = "jporretti@itba.edu.ar"
    sender_password = ""
    receiver_email = "joacoporretti@gmail.com"
    login_email = "joacoporretti@gmail.com"
    login_password = ""

    # set up the URL to check
    url = "https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services"

    # set up the webdriver (assuming you have installed chromedriver)
    service = Service("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

    # navigate to the login page
    driver.get("https://prenotami.esteri.it/")

    # wait for the email and password fields to appear
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    
    email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Email")))
    password_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Password")))

    # enter the email and password
    email_field.send_keys(login_email)
    password_field.send_keys(login_password)

    # submit the login form
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # wait for the dashboard page to load after submitting the login form
    wait.until(EC.url_contains("https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services"))

    # add a short wait time
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    # navigate to the page to check for appointments
    driver.get(url)

    # wait for the page to load
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pnl_app")))
    except:
        print("Page did not load properly.")
        driver.quit()
        return

    # rest of the code for checking appointments

if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_appointments()
```

i tried to execute the code, and like i said, it opens up google chrome, goes to the site, but fails after the sign in.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is your desired effect? Sorry maybe I didn't understand your question correctly, but I can't reproduce what's wrong with the code here.

Comment: After signing in i get a white website that says "Unavailable", and everything stops there. I would like to sign in, press the button i need to press to check available dates, and if the message for no available dates appears after that i want to receive an email saying there are no dates.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site blocks the automatic login. I am still figuring out how (once you get this info then it is easier to overcome the issue)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the problem is a captcha.

If the site is meant to be checked by humans, the captcha will probably be there, blocking robots from accessing.

Have you tried to log in without the bot, to see if you have to fill in a captcha?

Comment: Yeah, without the bot i can log in normally.

Comment: Does it have any kind of [captcha](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA) (the thing that checks you're human). It's set in a lot of places and it doesn't allow bots in

Answer (score 0):

The Unavailable message occurs because after the POST to https://prenotami.esteri.it/Home/Login the response of authentication is empty and redirect a GET request to the page https://prenotami.esteri.it/UserArea that will return the html content.